# Spliting column values into groups and summing up values from linked table

Tags: sql

I have two tables in SQL, they are linked by Customer_ID.

customers

```
customer_id;  account_created;  company_name;  city;
1             11/10/2011        abc            new york
2             1/1/2018          xyz            los angeles
3             11/10/2012        finance        new jersey
4             21/04/2013        juices         san francisco
```

orders

```
order_id;  customer_id;  order_date;  shipping date;  order_value;  currency;
100        1             19/10/2019   20/10/2019      4000          USD
101        3             1/10/2019    2/10/2019       300           USD
102        2             13/11/2019   15/11/2019      7000          USD
103        4             12/9/2019    20/9/2019       100           USD
104        1             10/11/2019   12/11/2019      3000          USD
```

I would like to divide orders into two regions: East (contains New York, Boston and New Jersey) and West (Los Angeles, San Francisco) and then show sum of order_value for both regions in a way:

```
 Region    sum of order_value
 East      10000
 West      20000
```

Here are the tables, sorry they are in image, I can't format them (will learn asap!)

[image: customers]

[image: orders]

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Data can be formatted here as text by using code formatting (which you already know how to do). I have downvoted, but will be very happy to undownvote once it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems really weird to call "New Jersey" as city.  In any case, you want a `case` expression of some sort to assign the region, and then aggregation:

```
select (case when city in ('New York', 'Boston', 'New Jersey') then 'East'
             when city in ('Los Angeles', 'San Francisco') then 'West'

             else '???'
        end) as region,
       sum(order_value)
from customers c join
     orders o
     on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by (case when city in ('New York', 'Boston', 'New Jersey') then 'East'
               when city in ('Los Angeles', 'San Francisco') then 'West'

               else '???'
          end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a third table with fields: City|Region

Then you just join the 3 tables and group by Region and sum your orders value.
No code needed.